# What's the Best Practice for incorporate Semantic Versioning using TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, nuget, assemblyinfo, semantic-versioning

TeamCity is a great CI tool and we also use Semantic Versioning to manage our DLL version for a long time, now we are reaching a idea to integrate TeamCity and Semantic Versioning together, meanwhile we do some research on this topic, Let's say the Version infor like

MajorVersion.MinorVersion.PatchVersion.BuildNumber

The buildNumber we always use teamcity buildnumber, and other 3 versions we maintains within assemblyinfo.cs
the question here is - how can we use teamcity to feed its build number into assemblyinfo.cs, i can find Msbuild support this parameter, and is there any best practice to handle the same thing? and we also would like to feed the whole version into nuget packs as the published version information to our developers

Thanks a lot

Comment: Gary, what direction did you end up taking? I'm starting down a similar path.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to describe the approach that works for me in this article. 
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/144809/continuous-integration-using-nuget-and-teamcity/

Notice NuGet doesn't support SemVer fully (yet), e.g. PrereleaseTags combined with build numbers won't work the way you expect it to. I've described a bit of guidance on versioning in [Top 10 NuGet (Anti-)Patterns on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj851071.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use AssemblyInfo Patcher feature. Build features are configured on the Build Steps page of the build configuration settings. It's documented [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/AssemblyInfo+Patcher). If you have are keep your AssemblyInfo in not standard place you can use [MSBuild community task](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) `AssemblyInfo` to rewrite it by msbuild.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very complete SemVer Build Number meta-runner available as part of the TeamCity meta-runners power pack (https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack).

Here's a description of the features by the author:
http://johanleino.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/teamcity-meta-runner-semantic-version-build-number/

The SemVer Build Number meta-runner is a runner based on PowerShell. It can (at the time of this posting):

- Get version numbers from nuspec (nuget) files.
- Use manual version numbers (from parameters if you need that). Overrides other methods.
- Include TeamCity build counter.
- Include VCS revision.
- Translate Git commit hash to short hash.
- Ignore Build MetaData if needed.
- Logging etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a blog post I wrote of how to create version numbers from the first two numbers from `AssemblyInfo.cs` for a C# .Net project and adding a build counter and branch name to form the complete version number. Can easily be modified for other situations, it's just scripts together with the **File Content Replacer** build feature.

http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/generating-semantic-version-build-numbers-in-teamcity/

Hope this helps.